# How calculate breakeven point for first and last sell orders if i have multiple open sell and buy orders mql4

Tags: mql4, mt4, expert-advisor

I have multiple open sell orders and buy orders ,how can I close only first sell order and last sell order together at the breakeven point in mt4 mql4